# Getting nil error for lineHeight in textview

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a textview with following code. But I am getting

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Error.

My code:

```
var textField : UITextView!
textField = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 36))
self.view.addSubview(textField)
textField.editable=true
var amountOfLinesToBeShown:CGFloat = 6
var maxHeight:CGFloat = textField.font.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown
textField.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textField.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
```

I am getting error for `textField.font.lineHeight`

How can I fix it?

Comment: font is an optional property. Check it before accessing to lineheight. My advice is to set the font of your textfield and the access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> var font: UIFont! // default is nil. use system font 12 pt

So you need to do:

```
if let currentFont = textField.font {
    let maxHeight:CGFloat = currentFont.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown
    textField.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textField.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
}
```

And you should use `let` instead of `var` when possible, so:

```
let textField : UITextView?

let amountOfLinesToBeShown = CGFloat(6)

let maxHeight:CGFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the optionals and CGFloats for you:

```
var textField : UITextView?
textField = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(36)))
self.view.addSubview(textField!)
textField!.editable=true
var amountOfLinesToBeShown = CGFloat(6)
var maxHeight = CGFloat(textField!.font.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown)
textField!.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textField!.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView`'s font property is optional. You need to unwrap it. In your example it will look like following:

```
var maxHeight:CGFloat = textField.frame.size.height
if let font = textField.font {
    maxHeight = font.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown
}
```